# Is there an equivalent to JavaScripts '||' in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby

In JavaScript, I can write the awesomely expressive:

```
console.log(foo.name || 'No Name');
```

Is there any Ruby equivalent to that short expression?

Comment: is it not the same? [look here](http://invisibleblocks.com/2007/06/11/rubys-other-ternary-operator/)

Comment: -1 It works exactly the same way in Ruby. IMHO one should first try before asking, especially given the fact the Ruby has a great REPL (irb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use ruby rarely, but it should be just about identical.

```
>> name = false
=> false
>> puts name || "no name"
no name
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same to Ruby:

```
def test(x)
  puts x
end

var = nil
test( var || 'No Name') #=> No Name

var = 'something'
test( var || 'No Name') #=> something
```

Also you can use the same technique to initialize a variable when it is not initialized:

```
var ||= 'data'
```

Comment: Just a side note : Unfortunately you can't do `somevar ||= 'data'` in javascript.